# Posição atual no arquivo - C

Tags: c, arquivo, stream-de-arquivos

Olá, estou com uma dúvida sobre manipulação de arquivos em C e não estou conseguindo encontrar a resposta para isso. 
Estou gravando um registro "a" do tipo "Aluno" em um arquivo binário "arquivoBinario":

```
    fwrite(&a, sizeof(Aluno), 1, arquivoBinario);
```

Eu sei que essa fução retorna o número de elementos que foram escritos com sucesso no arquivo. O que eu gostaria de saber é em que posição no arquivo esse registro foi escrito.

Eu preciso dessa posição para fazer um acesso rápido à esse registro que foi salvo nesse arquivo sem ser necesário procurar por todos sequencialmente.

Me desculpem por qualquer erro na postagem e me corrijam por favor, é minha primeira pergunta aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `fwrite` escreve na posição corrente em que o ficheiro vai e modifica essa posição X bytes para a frente de acordo com os bytes que foram escritos.

A posição atual no arquivo é controlada pelas escritas e leituras anteriores, feitas com `fwrite` e `fread` respetivamente.

> O que eu gostaria de saber é em que posição no arquivo esse registro foi escrito

Antes de escrever podemos consultar a posição corrente com `ftell`:

```
long posicao = ftell (arquivoBinario);
```

E será a partir desse byte que os dados serão escritos.

> Eu preciso dessa posição para fazer um acesso rápido à esse registro
>   que foi salvo nesse arquivo sem ser necesário procurar por todos
>   sequencialmente

Para modificar diretamente a posição atual no arquivo podemos utilizar `fseek`, da seguinte forma:

```
fseek (arquivoBinario, 10 , SEEK_SET); 
/*fseek(arquivo,byte a posicionar,do inicio);*/
```

Aqui vemos que recebe o arquivo, seguido da quantidade de bytes e o modo de posicionamento, em que o `SEEK_SET` refere a partir do inicio. O exemplo anterior posiciona o arquivo no decimo byte a contar do inicio.

Alternativamente podemos utilizar `SEEK_END` como ultimo parâmetro se quisermos posicionar a partir do fim.

Comment: Nossa cara, muito obrigado. Parece muito simples acho que eu não estava sabendo como procurar pela solução mas resolveu meu problema perfeitamente. Vlw mesmo.